# How to handle undelivered messages on GAE Channel API?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

The following Google reference page says "No error is returned if the message cannot be delivered":
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/functions

In contrast, Socket.IO has ack callbacks on messages so you can handler success/error:
http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Does anyone suggest a solution to achieve the same goal using the Channel API? Otherwise, Channel API is only useful for volatile messaging. And I would rather not reinvent the wheel to try to achieve this effect by writing a transactional system for messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that the Channel API is unidirectional and non blocking, so there is no way to wait for a response or specify a callback.  However...

The [Elements of the Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/#Python_Elements_of_the_Channel_API) section of the [Channel Python API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/) says the role of the server includes "Receiving update messages from clients via HTTP requests".  Therefore by sending a unique message identifier in each channel message, clients could acknowledge them asynchronously via HTTP.  The server could re-send the unacknowledged messages after each one times out.

Maybe it's still bad news, because this suggestion looks too much like your "writing a transactional system for messaging" although the asynchronous part would be better that synchronous socket.io.

Comment: Thanks @martin-berends. Given that I need both reliable messaging and acks, and I'd rather not build multiple tiers of messaging (i.e., channel + polling for whatever was missed), I'm planning to just timestamp the models which the client needs updates for, and poll frequently.